# htaccess rewrite rule to include a string if it is not there

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, preg-match

How can i update my url from htaccess file to include a string if it is not there. Before my site was developed in drupal 6 and we migrated to drupal 7. My mobile urls' got changed. For example:

```
http://m.example.com/en/terms-of-use to http://m.example.com/en/m-terms-of-use
http://m.example.com/en/contact-us to http://m.example.com/en/m-contact-us
```

Google is already indexed with my previous url's and getting 404 errors. So i planned for an auto redirection from htaccess.
How can i do this without inter-fairing the main site ie. http://example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(en)/((?!m-).+)$ /$1/m-$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: You're too quick... i don't even bother answering :D

Comment: is this correct if i have a mobile domain and if i only want to change the urls for mobile domain? RewriteRule ^(m.example.com)/(en)/((?!m-).+)$ /$1/m-$2 [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: No that is not correct, you cannot match domain name in RewriteRule. Let me know your requirement clearly and I will update my answer.